# Can sIFR js files be combined into 1 js file?

Tags: javascript, performance, sifr, compression

In the new sifr 3, the author has implemented the ability to combine the css files into 1 file. There are 4 .js files total and I was wondering if there were any ideas how to combine these files for a faster loading time on the client side and also I was wondering if there was any way to just include the sIFR css styles in an already existing css file.

These modifications would greatly decrease the load/waiting time on the end user and I was wondering if there was any thought for that on upcoming builds or if there were any ideas on how to accomplish this idea.

Answer (score 0):

There should be only two JavaScript files actually deployed in production, but yes, you can combine them. Just don't try to compress the `sifr.js` yourself, it's already compressed for you.